# Can the C# preprocessor look at constant string values?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a MadLib library for a kid I'm tutoring.  The MadLib class has the following:

```
// Finds fields
private static readonly Regex PromptValueRegex = new Regex("<([^>]+)>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// text of our story
private readonly string Story;

...

/// <summary>
/// Creates a new MadLib object with the given story text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="story">The text of the story with blank field names denoted by &lt;blank name&gt;.</param>
public MadLib(string story)
{
    if (story == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Story cannot be null.");
    }

    if (story.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        throw new EmptyStoryException();
    }

    Story = story;

    SetupPromptDictionary();
}
```

The story detects what in olde-time MadLibs would be blanks by finding `"<blank name>"` via the regex `<([^>]+)>`.

I would like to give a compile-time warning if the story passed into the constructor can be determined to have no `<` or `>` characters.  Is this possible?

Comment: How do you want to give a **compile time** warning for something that's determined in **runtime**?

Comment: If he uses something like `new MadLib("my story")`, as story cannot be set after the MadLib object is initialized, then for sure that MadLib object is warning-worthy.

Comment: new MadLib("my story") is runtime code, warnings are compile time.

Comment: But `"my story"` is a constant.  Constants can be determined compile time.

Comment: That's not a compiler error/warning, though. It falls into the same category as if he uses something like `new MadLib(null)`

Comment: Okay, that was my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Via the comments, this is impossible.  If it ever becomes possible, let me know!